# ¿Cómo revertir el orden de un array de objetos?

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando e ordenar un array de objetos alfabéticamente dependiendo el valor de la variable `filters`.

Si la variable `filters` es `true`, quiero que se me ordene el array de objetos alfabéticamente por la propiedad `name` (cosa que funciona bien), pero si la variable `filters` es `false`, quiero que no realice orden alguno si no que deje el orden como cargaron los datos.

¿Cómo podría hacer para revertir el orden teniendo en cuenta que los valores de `filters`, `true`/`false` vienen de dos botones diferentes?

```
if(filters === true){
    //sorting pokemons by name
    pokemons.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}else{
  //mostrar orden normal como cargaron los datos por defecto
}
```

Comment: No necesitas comparar la variable con `true`, es suficiente con poner `if (filters)`, pues Javascript lo compara automáticamente con `true` por si solo.

Comment: Además de eso no entiendo tu problema, pues si `filters` es `false`, NUNCA se va a ejecutar el `.sort` y no se modificará el array a menos que hayas ejecutado el `.sort` antes.

Comment: Es que quiere dar click a un boton y ordenar alfabeticamente y despues de estar ordenado dar click al boton de dejar como estaba. La unica forma es tener 2 variables, una con el orden inicial y nunca modificarla. Para poder tener ese estado.

Comment: se modifica porque si el usuario da click en el botón de ordenar por orden alfabético, y después en el otro simpre va a quedar ordenado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe ser algo así, si quieres mantener el estado inicial

```
// Esta linea debe ser inmediatamente despues de obtener el array pokemons
let pokemons_unordered = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( pokemons ))

if(filters === true){
    //sorting pokemons by name
    pokemons.sort(function(a, b) {
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase();
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase();
        if (nameA < nameB) {
          return -1;
        }
        if (nameA > nameB) {
          return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    console.log({ pokemons })
}else{
    //mostrar orden normal como cargaron los datos por defecto
    pokemons = pokemons_unordered
    console.log({ pokemons })
}
```